# Where is the clone() system call define in the linux kernel?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, clone

I have been looking for it, but could not find it.

lxr should do a better job analyzing the Linux kernel code (not simply because not being to find `clone()`, but because of whole list of other things).

Thanks.

Comment: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.12.6/kernel/fork.c#L1681

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Unix stack exchange site has

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87551/which-file-in-kernel-specifies-fork-vfork-to-use-sys-clone-system-call

which answers your question.

Comment: Good enough...Thank you!